# slideUP animation for post after each other on scroll?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, loops, each, velocity.js

I'm having a wordpress website with my post being display like below ( nothing extraordinary)

```
<section id="grid">
<div class="container-fluid">
      <?php $custom_query = new WP_Query('cat=-9'); // exclude category 9
while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post" tabindex="-1" data-easein="slideUpIn" >
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5"><h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
    </div>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
</div>
</section>
```

Id like to have the animation ( a slideUpIn by velocity.js) one post after each other, for this I am using this: ( I'd like to avoid delay for this, but to have the animation starting once user reach the post on the window)

```
 jQuery(function ($) { 

$(window).scroll(function () {
console.log($(window).scrollTop());
var topDivHeight = $("#description").height();
var viewPortSize = $(window).height();

var triggerAt = 500;
var triggerHeight = (topDivHeight - viewPortSize) + triggerAt;

if ($(window).scrollTop() >= triggerHeight) {
        // alert("Your book is overdue.");

    // $('.post').css('visibility', 'visible').hide().fadeIn();
    $(".post").each(function(i){
     $(this).delay(i).velocity("transition.slideUpIn", 2000)
    $(this).off('scroll');
})
}
}); });
```

Which start to animate after the div description.

The problem i had was it was making display ALL the post in one, so Ive added the each function as you can see. But with this function, all the post are animated in a loop and doesn't stop to being animated . ..

Anyone knows how I could achieve this ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

It is "looping" because it keeps restarting the slide on every scroll event since there is nothing to stop it from running more than once. The `.off` does not have any effect because the scroll event is not registered on the `this` item, but on the `window`.

Also, `scrollTop()` is only being compared to a fixed height, rather than the top of each individual post. The `scrollTop` test needs to be inside the `each`.

Something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());

    var viewPortSize = $(window).height();

    $(".post").each(function(i){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + viewPortSize >= $(this).offset().top && !$(this).attr('showing')) {
            $(this).attr('showing', true)
            $(this).delay(i).velocity("transition.slideUpIn", 2000);
        }
    });
});
```

Here the `'showing'` attribute is set on the element once it starts showing, and prevents the slide animation to be triggered again if `showing` is already set.

You might want to add the trigger height into the `$(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top` test depending on your use case.

[Here's a demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/reooL0po/1/)